# Redactor WYSIWYG - formattingPre not working

Tags: html, wysiwyg, redactor

I'd like to use following tags in the editor.

```
<pre><code>
  # stuff 
</code></pre>
```

[According to the documentation](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/#set-formattingPre), **formattingPre** should be set to **true**, but this isn't working.

The result is always:

```
<pre>
&lt;code&gt;# stuff
</pre>
```

Both **pre**-tags are kept, the first **code**-tag is translated into HMTL entities and the last **code**-tag is removed.

Are there any fixes for this?